# Problem installing packages using pip on CentOS (SSLError)

Tags: python, ssl, pip, openssl, centos

i am using centos 7.6.1810

i have downloaded these dependencies for python

```
yum install openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

I then download python3.10.9

```
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.9/Python-3.10.9.tgz
```

After unpacking I then try to do the install step

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

The install step finishes suspiciously quickly, and when I try to use pip I get the following error

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.5.0
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

I thought this would be solved by downloading the openssl dependency

Does anyone know what my issue is or how i can troubleshoot?

Comment: Inspect the output from the `./configure` step. Is there any information concerning the openssl library? Possibly the version in CentOS 7 is too old.

Comment: @larsks there seems to be many errors relating to the altinstall step, but the configure step looks clean. What I tried doing was importing the ssl module in python and got an error that the module is not available. So even though I have the stuff installed it looks as though it was not included during the build process. There seem to options relating to providing the path to openssl during the configure step but I really do not want to have to repeat that for every dependency :(

Comment: `sudo wget` Please don't! You don't need `sudo` to download a file!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow the steps outlined in your question, then when building Python I see the error:

```
Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires a OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer
```

That's what I was suggesting in my comment. You will need to install a newer version of the openssl library in order to build Python with ssl support.

Alternatively, you could consider running containerized Python using `podman` (or `docker`) to get a more recent version without needing to build anything.

Comment: *You will need to install a newer version of the openssl library*  Centos 7 supports OpenSSL v1.1.1 with the `openssl11` set of packages: `yum install openssl11 openssl11-devel openssl11-debuginfo`